# Typescript: type-level math when maping over a union type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to use type-level math to map over a union type in typescript to produce a new union that is a function of the first one?

E.g., I'd like to use an existing union type:

```
type foo = 768 | 1024 | 1280;
```

in order to produce this union (each option divided by 16):

```
type bar = 48 | 64 | 80;
```

Where the number of members in the union is flexible, i.e., it could just as well be :
 `600 | 768 | 1024 | 1280`

Comment: Your example is problematic; mapping over a union type is straightforward with [distributive conditional types](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). But multiplying a numeric literal type by two is not directly supported; it would need something like [ms/TS#26382](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) to be implemented, or a complicated/fragile workaround in the meantime. Maybe change the example to something where you know how to do the operation for a single element? Unless you're really asking about type-level math.

Comment: And your example is dividing by two, not multiplying, I guess.  See [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8Law) for what I would do for the particular example; if that seems too crazy and you don't really care about math, you should consider changing the example (e.g., turn `2 | 4 | 8` into `{x: 2} | {x: 4} | {x: 8}`, which is [much less crazy](https://tsplay.dev/Nd30dw))

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. I am really asking about type-level math. [The code you linked to](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8Law) seems to be pretty much what I need, but I'm not sure I understand what's going on there or how I would change it if I wanted to divide by another number rather than 2.

Comment: I’m happy to elaborate in an answer when I get a chance, but in the meantime you might want to edit the question to ask about math (which is the tricky/impossible part) and not mapping over unions (which is the easy part)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer to this is that it is not currently possible in TypeScript to perform arbitrary mathematical computations on numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types).  There is a (fairly longstanding) open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) asking for this.  You might want to go there and give it a , and since its status is "awaiting more feedback", you might want to leave a comment there detailing your use case if you think it's compelling.  But it probably won't make much of a difference, so for now it's best to just proceed on the assumption that type-level math won't happen anytime soon.

You can convince the compiler to perform some sorts of mathematical operations by manipulating [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) like `[any, any, any]`.  Tuple types have `length` properties which are numeric literals, and you can use [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) and [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) to change tuple lengths.

---

That means you will be limited to doing operations on non-negative whole numbers (you can't have a tuple of length `3.14159` or `-2`), and since type recursion has a limit of about <strike>~25 levels of depth</strike> 1000 levels of depth (**UPDATE**: TS4.5 has increased this to about ~1000 levels for [tail-recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) so this is a bit better now, but it still is pretty small when it comes to numbers), it is hard to get things working with large numbers.  The intuitive implementations tend to only work with numbers less than 1000 or so.  There are some less intuitive implementations that can work with numbers in the thousands or tens of thousands (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-674514787) on a related GitHub issue) but even these involve actually building tuples of those lengths, and can thus bog down the compiler.  Even if you are incredibly clever, you will probably write something complicated and fragile.  Edge cases are *everywhere*.

Your original code example was dividing small numbers by two, which can be done using recursion like this:

```
type DivideByTwo<N extends number, T extends 0[] = []> = N extends any ?
  0 extends [...T, ...T, 0][N] ? T['length'] : DivideByTwo<N, [0, ...T]> : never;

type X = DivideByTwo<6 | 10 | 30>; // type X = 3 | 5 | 15
```

This works by taking a number `N` and a tuple `T` which starts off empty (`[]`).  If two copies of `T` concatenated together followed by a single element has an element at index `N`, then `T` is at least as big as twice `N`, and we just return the length of `T`.  Otherwise, `T` is too small, so we add an element to it and try again.  This chops small numbers in half: if `N` is `10`, then `T` becomes `[]`, then `[0]`, then `[0,0]`, then `[0,0,0]`, then `[0,0,0,0]`, then `[0,0,0,0,0]` which satisfies the original check, and so you get `5`.

The `N extends any...` part makes the operation [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over unions in `N`, so unions of inputs become unions in outputs... so `DivideByTwo<10 | 20>` is `5 | 10` (in some order).

---

But then you changed your example to be dividing numbers significantly larger by sixteen.  To even begin doing this I'd have to start using the trick of repeated doubling of tuples (which means the recursion depth limit ends up looking like a limit on the logarithm of the number and not the number itself).  And trying to do that for both the dividend (the numerator, the big number) and the divisor (the denominator, the 16 here) is not worth it to me to even try.  Here's a hardcoded thing that seems to work for dividing by sixteen:

```
type Quadruple<T extends any[]> = [...T, ...T, ...T, ...T]

type Explode<N extends number, R extends never[][]> =
  Quadruple<R[0]>[N] extends never ? R : Explode<N, [[...R[0], ...R[0]], ...R]>;

type BinaryBuilder<N extends number, R extends never[][], B extends never[]> =
  Quadruple<[...B, never]>[N] extends never ? B :
  Quadruple<[...R[0], ...B]>[N] extends never ? BinaryBuilder<N, R extends [R[0], ...infer U] ? U extends never[][] ? U : never : never, B> :
  BinaryBuilder<N, R extends [R[0], ...infer U] ? U extends never[][] ? U : never : never, [...R[0], ...B]>;

type CutTupleInFour<N extends number> = number extends N ? any[] : N extends number ?
  Explode<N, [[never]]> extends infer U ? U extends never[][]
  ? BinaryBuilder<N, U, []> : never : never : never;

type DivideByFour<N extends number> = CutTupleInFour<N>['length']

type DivideBySixteen<N extends number> = DivideByFour<DivideByFour<N>>


type Foo = 768 | 1024 | 1280;
type Bar = DivideBySixteen<Foo>
// type Bar = 64 | 48 | 80
```

You like that?  Yeah, me neither.  Even explaining how it works in detail is too much for me to do.  I'll say that it works by dividing by four twice (when I tried sixteen directly the compiler bogged down and wouldn't complete in a reasonable time), and that it divides by four by building up tuples of repeated-doubling lengths, stops when it has one that's too big, and then joins them together to form one of the right length.

A sketch: let's say we're supposed to divide `80` by 16.  The compiler first divides `80` by 4.  It builds tuples of lengths `32`, `16`, `8`, `4`, `2`, and `1`.  It then concatenates the ones of lengths `16` and `4` to get one of length `20`.  Now it divides `20` by 4, by building tuples of lengths `8`, `4`, `2`, and `1`.  It then concatenates the ones of lengths `4` and `1` to get one of length `5`.  And the result is `5`.

But yuck, ugly, awful.  Nothing you'd want to do in production.

---

If I were you, I'd re-examine why you want the type system to do this for you instead of doing it yourself.  And if you still have a good reason, it might be more effective lobbying for it at microsoft/TypeScript#26382 than it is to jump through hoops with tuples.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-VmkkbCbw20Ov4Q0hSu7Pd6pHUreE02YrDaq1Ya0hYsHmt1enskLgKKA0HhKJl+GgfdnTOotDp9KHh6pc1HEg3cGGR5G0DG40gE7r9YaK7h9DO0Bnkovp8v8wvimuN0nt030zbcIes8Yc6fUp3u72KP2dLUC1OHHWNpdqSOhIAAqik4HHhGHTRpBYGFjBoGtMu+i4C0a7viAPYEF+A6-pOz5hIBjaRMBoEQfmCH-vucFUYh+4MahDi3tW94ts66qoEQQhbhApAAGJiPgg5uER04Bjozj2KOgbQTIqTeNg1iIWJoQSWOaD+GuxaZF6KZlg4Fj7vWzj-uRWkIak1HiUhK5zmub5dthn7fqJ+hgXUzRMXmKG+XZrZqu2Iz8IIQkiUOtmyVJLgoDxfGCcJomOBk2TAHkhROm2-QhVU1IUMYSiRep-qadJZQ8KF2DhYOuVhUl0iOI4PTZcgQliC4koTIqZxmOy0pnOyipmN0QX9Lg2HDJVeUFYoRXtc1LAwlxE1afYEwDbM0o9bMw1XD0QA)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the very in depth answer and explanation.